# Redirection with ssl not working all times

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I'm trying to redirect many requests:

```
http://www.site.example -> https://site.example
http://site.example -> https://site.example
https://www.site.example -> https://site.example
```

Only the last one, i'ts not working, returning `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`

I've tested many Conds and Rules, this is the main:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Aditional:**

In new's Google Search Console still requires add all versions (http,https,www,non-www) and select the preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only the last one, i'ts not working, returning SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

This has nothing to do with redirects and thus your config does not help. It instead means that HTTPS is not or not properly configured for the domain you are trying to access, i.e. `www.site.example`. Plain HTTP still might work for this domain but HTTPS will not and the error happens before the redirect can even be sent by the server.

Comment: @Lucius0101: yes